# I am getting an error trying to do a git push to a repository in my github codespace

Tags: git, github, codespaces

I have created a github codespace that I attached (I think) to a particular github repository that I own.  However, when I attempt to do a git push to the remote repo,
I'm getting the following error:

```
remote: Permission to <username>/<reponame>.git denied to <username>.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/<username>/>reponame>/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

How can I check that the codespace is attached to the repo in question?  Any other debugging hints?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are trying to link codespace to some other repository that you own. But by default, Codespace limits access to only repository from which it was created.

So you can either create a brand new codespace for your other repository.

`OR`

If you want to access other repository from your existing codespace then you will have to update your `devcontainer.json` to set additional permissions to access this other repository.

Please refer to these official docs -

1. https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/managing-your-codespaces/managing-repository-access-for-your-codespaces
2. To set additional permissions - https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/managing-your-codespaces/managing-repository-access-for-your-codespaces#setting-additional-repository-permissions

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: I still can't seem to get this to work.   In my root of my git repository in the codespace environment I added a .devcontainer directory and in that I created a devcontainer.json file.  The file contains the following:

Comment: {
  "customizations": {
    "codespaces": {
      "repositories": {
        "<username>/<reponame>": {
          "permissions": {
            "issues": "write"
          }
        }
      }   
    }   
  }
}

Comment: @redmage123, Make sure you add devcontainer.json in orignal repo from which codespace was originally created. Simply adding it in local codespace won't work. Best way to do it is from GitHub itself, please follow below link for same. Also please note that new configuration will take effect only if you recreate the codespace after adding the devcontainer.json, your existing codespace won't respect the config change.  https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/setting-up-your-project-for-codespaces/adding-a-dev-container-configuration/introduction-to-dev-containers#adding-a-devcontainerjson-file

Comment: @redmage123 to add to this, you need to delete the codespace and create a new one, doing a rebuild won't work.
Once you set your permissions and create a new codespace, a prompt will show up on GitHub asking you to approve the new permissions.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I check that the codespace is attached to the repo in question

You can see all your GitHub codespaces via https://github.com/codespaces

```
user1/repo1 <-- this is the username/repo the codespaces attached
codespace1

user2/repo2
codespace2
```

For example, assuming you are `user2`:

- If `codespace1` is attached to `user1/repo1` but  and `user1` does not grant you write permission to `user1/repo1`, then `git push` under `codespace1` will result in permission denied.
- Assuming you do not have write access to `user1/repo1`, the best practice is to **first fork** `user1/repo1` to `user2/repo1`, **then create** a codespace under `user2/repo1`. Thus, you can push to your fork (`user2/repo1`) and send pull request to upstream (`user1/repo1`). If you first create a codespace under `user1/repo1`, then fork `user1/repo1` to `user2/repo1`, you can neither push to the upstream (`user1/repo1`) nor push to your fork (`user2/repo1`) under that codespace.